# Is there a difference in the signing procedure of a release-apk and release-aar

Tags: android, android-studio, release, signing, aar

I read up details about how a release apk is signed with a public key(digital certificate) and the private key is maintained by the developer.
Now my question is that if I am only releasing an aar, then does the same concept apply to release-aar/ debug-aar. As in is the same signing procedure required for releasing an .aar file.

Thanks

Comment: No its not, but you usually still want/have to sign it. When you publish your library to a maven repository (for example Bintray) you are given the option to sign your library.

Comment: Signing your library - just like with an apk - proves that it came from the original developer and hasn't been altered in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a difference - APKs are distributed via Google Play whereas AARs are not. The two have different uses and requirements. APKs submitted to Google Play must be signed. Different Maven servers/repos have different requirements. Artifacts uploaded to Maven Central must be signed, whereas if you deploy your own Maven server, there of course does not need to be such a requirement.

If you're looking to sign your aar, you may want to look at the Gradle signing plugin: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html

Comment: Thanks, one follow up question. I am working on an aar that the customer will finally consume and integrate with their application(apk). In such a case, ideally  should the aar I am releasing be signed or not?

Comment: It won't make a difference to their final APK. But, it's ideal for it to be signed so that the client/customer can verify the AAR really came from you, and not somebody else.